# How to pass database value from controller to dashboard in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a method in my controller, PostsController:

```
public function index()
{
    $post = Posts::where('id', '1')->get(['post']);
    return $post;
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('test', [PostsController::class, 'index']);
```

into test.blade.php in my views folder, and show it with

```
{{ $post }}
```

This works perfectly. However, when I try to do the exact same thing to the dashboard.blade.php, I get

> ```
> Undefined variable $post
> ```

When trying to get this data on dashboard, I use this in app.php instead.

```
Route::get('dashboard', [PostsController::class, 'index']);
```

I was expecting to get the same data on the dashboard as in test.blade.php, but it cannot find the variable anymore as soon as I change the view in the route. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your controller method that returns your view named "**dashboard**".

Comment: nothing here is returning a view, btw ... also `get` would return a Collection not a single Model

Comment: @cengsemihsahin: It's the default dashboard that comes with Laravel Breeze. I was unable to find a controller for it, but I am very new to Laravel so that might be why.

Comment: @lagbox: I'm not trying to return a view, but send a variable to a view to use it there. Unless I misunderstood what you meant? Very new to Laravel still.  Is creating a view in the controller and then returning best practise?

Comment: what view are you "creating"? ... there is no code here that has anything to do with a 'view' at all

Comment: I created the view file manually (just a new file, test.blade.php) and sent the data from the controller to use there. I'm trying to do the same with the default dashboard.blade.php that came with Breeze. I'm using the way they show in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aoqj5nuwBQI&ab_channel=CodeWithDary)  @lagbox

Comment: "sent the data from the controller to use there" ... where is the code that does that? where is the code that returns a view that was passed this data?

Comment: I added this "Route::get('test', [PostsController::class, 'index']);" to web.php in routes, and I was then able to call {{ $post }} from the controller in test.blade.php. That is all I've done, and all the code is in the original post. Theres nothing more, the rest is just default laravel 9 with breeze.

Comment: your `test.blade.php` file only has `{{ $post }}` in it?  that "view" isn't being used at all ... returning data from your Controller has nothing to do with a view file (you would have to return a view for a view to be rendered)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
return view('test', [
    'post' => Posts::where('id', '1')->get()
]);
```

and if your test.blade is not directly inside the views folder you need to specify the folder like that: view('folderName.test', ...)

and for more information, you can check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers

Comment: In the controller, instead of just returning $post? Didn't work, unfortunately. Test.blade is directly in the views folder.